# Extracting inner file from zip file with python

Tags: python, zip, unzip

I am able to extract the inner file, but it extracts the entire chain.
Suppose the following file structure

```
v a.zip
    v folder1
        v folder2
            > inner.txt
```

and suppose I want to extract `inner.txt` to some folder `target`.
Currently what happens when I try to do this is that I end up extracting `folder1/folder2/inner.txt` to `target`. Is it possible to extract the single file instead of the entire chain of directories? So that when `target` is opened, the only thing inside is `inner.txt`.

EDIT:
Using python zip module to unzip files and extract only the inner files to the desired location.

Comment: What doer _Python_ have to do with all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **-j** (*junk paths (do not make directories)*) modifier (old *v5.52* has it). Here's the full list: [[DIE.Linux]: unzip(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip), or you could simply run *(${PATH_TO}/)unzip* in the terminal, and it will output the argument list.

Considering that you want to extract the file in a folder called *target*, use the command (you may need to specify the path to *unzip*):

```
"unzip" -j "a.zip" -d "target" "folder1/folder2/inner.txt"
```

**Output** (*Win*, but for *Nix* it's the same thing):

> ```
> (py35x64_test) c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047439536>"unzip" -j "a.zip" -d "target" "folder1/folder2/inner.txt"
> Archive:  a.zip
>   inflating: target/inner.txt
> ```

**Output** (without ***-j***):

> ```
> (py35x64_test) c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q047439536>"unzip" "a.zip" -d "target" "folder1/folder2/inner.txt"
> Archive:  a.zip
>   inflating: target/folder1/folder2/inner.txt
> ```

Or, since you mentioned *Python*,

*code00.py*:

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile


def extract_without_folder(arc_name, full_item_name, folder):
    with ZipFile(arc_name) as zf:
        file_data = zf.read(full_item_name)
    with open(os.path.join(folder, os.path.basename(full_item_name)), "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(file_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    extract_without_folder("a.zip", "folder1/folder2/inner.txt", "target")
```

Comment: So It's not really extracting. It's more like reading first and then writing? Or perhaps that is what extracting is and I'm just confused? :D

Comment: You're correct. Extracting means reading the file data out of the archive (that includes decompressing) and then write the file data to the disk, into the specified file name.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. :)

Comment: Is it possible to read out an entire folder in the same manner? So read folder 2 and write folder 2? Would I have to read and write every file in folder 2?

Comment: There is no actual data in a folder. A folder is just a container of files that contain data. Technically, (I just tried) you can read a folder from an archive but it will return am empty bytes stream. So I guess, you'd have to iterate over the files in the archive (`zf.filelist` and I saw that folders have the `external_attr` field set to *0x10*) and save them individually (creating the folder(s) first).

Answer (score 1):

The zip doesn't have a folder structure in the same way as on the filesystem - each file has a name that is its entire path.

You'll want to use a method that allows you to read the file contents (such as zipfile.open or zipfile.read), extract the part of the filename you actually want to use, and save the file contents to that file yourself.